# Google's gson library: JsonObject string encoding problem

Tags: java, json, encoding, jar, gson

Can somebody give me an idea of what is going on because I keep getting rather strange results from my tests. So, I have a maven project in IntelliJ and if i run this code (note the cyrillic string) inside the IDE the output is as expected.

```
JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
json.addProperty("message", "тест");
System.out.println("TEST:"+json.get("message").getAsString());
```

Output in IDE: TEST:тест

But if I package the project in a jar file the encoding of the JsonObject messes up somehow and the code above results in:

Output in console from jar: TEST:????

Things I tried:

- forcing the JVM to use -Dfile.enconding=UTF-8 just to see if this affects it but nothing changed.
- getting the bytes of the json.get("message").getAsString() and creating a new string with specified encoding new String( bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
- checked the IntelliJ run arguments of the project (nothing is specified)
- the problem persists with all characters with ASCII value above 127 (mentioning ASCII because UTF and most of the encodings inherit the first 127 character values from ASCII)
- It is not a console related problem because the same issue persists on UI elements that support UTF-8 here is an example: http://prntscr.com/lmca64 . This still persists ONLY on the app of the exported jar!

Do you have any idea what might cause this inconsistent behavior?
[link to the GSON library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson)

Update*:
After further testing here is the output of the following code:

```
    JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
    json.addProperty("message", "тест");
    byte[] jsonBytes = json.get("message").getAsString().getBytes();
    for(byte b : jsonBytes) {
        System.out.print(b+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    byte[] stringBytes = "тест".getBytes();
    for(byte b : stringBytes) {
        System.out.print(b+" ");
    }
```

IDE output:

```
-47 -126 -48 -75 -47 -127 -47 -126
-47 -126 -48 -75 -47 -127 -47 -126
```

Compiled jar console output:

```
63 63 63 63
63 63 63 63
```

**This in terms shows that both of the strings are the same but once packaged into a jar something happens.** 
[Decimal to text converter](https://www.browserling.com/tools/decimal-to-text)

Here is my pom.xml. May be I am doing something wrong while exporting the jar in wrong encoding?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<groupId>me.ivstiv</groupId>
<artifactId>Trapdoor-client</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>Trapdoor-client-1.0-fat</finalName>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>core.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Sounds like it's just a console issue to me. If you add `System.out.println("NOT IN JSON: тест");` I suspect you'll see the question marks there too.

Comment: @JonSkeet I edited my post and the list with tests. Even though you are right check this out: http://prntscr.com/lmca64 . It also affects UI elements which are capable of displaying cyrillic text.

Comment: It's very unclear what your screenshot is actually showing - in particular, we don't know what `addMsg` does. That screenshot doesn't look like valid Java code, either. There's also no sign that you tried what I suggested in terms of `System.out.println` - have you tried that directly? I would *start* by eliminating *everything* but the console. Once you've got working console output, you'll be in a better position. You could also print out the precise UTF-16 code units in each string (as numbers) to remove the output issues.

Comment: I don't think it matters what addMsg does as long as the 2 lines show that it is capable of receiving and displaying cyrillic text. But not if it comes from the JsonObject. I tested what you said initially and my comment started with "you are right" which implies that the console is not capable of displaying the text but this was just a mistake in testing, doesn't resolve the actual issue. The idea of printing the code units is brilliant I will test it and come back with results!

Comment: @JonSkeet I updated the post and added my pom.xml  file. Apparently the problem is not in the library but in the way I produce the jar file... which kind of contradicts with some of the previous tests but at this point I don't trust any previous output i got.

Comment: Currently you're printing bytes, without passing in an encoding. That's introducing an extra level of complexity - the system default encoding. You should print the integer value of each *character* in the string. But I suspect the problem with the difference in output isn't in packaging, but in compilation - the input encoding for the source code. If you use `\u` escaping instead in your string, so that your source file is entirely ASCII (but still representing non-ASCII characters) I suspect you'll at least get consistent output.

Comment: @JonSkeet I thought that the code points correspond to the byte values which are pretty much integer values of the characters but I was not aware of how UTF is structured. Anyway i lost a few hours of  wrong testing methods. After reading a bit more about the structure of UTF I revisited all of the tests but with code points and I found the class that creates the issue. It is not related to the gson library but has something to do with the compilation as you stated. I think i found a consistent way of recreating the bug  and  if I don't solve it in a few days I will make a more specific topic.